# How to build a framework in iOS for simulator and device (IPA)

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, ios-simulator, jwt

I am trying to use a library (framework) into our iOS project (https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift). It provides a cocoapod interface to add/use the framework. But unfortunately in my project, we are not incorporated cocoapods and at this point it is not possible to integrate the cocoapods into our iOS project. So I down loaded the source code of the framework from git hub and build the framework. So I got the .framework file and that we added into our project. This framework is working fine in simulator and when try to build the ipa (archive) it fails and saying that

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'decode'.
```

The method 'decode' is one of the member of JWTDecode. Can someone help me to build the framework that works for both simulator and devices. I am not familiar with building frameworks in iOS.

I am using the JWTDecode framework for decoding the a JWT token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the framework I built was only supporting for Simulator. I resolved the issue by building the framework for both device and simulator. The below post helped me on this.

https://medium.com/swiftindia/build-a-custom-universal-framework-on-ios-swift-549c084de7c8

Comment: This solution id dated, I'm still looking for a updated solution